# Cannot access iframe content running from PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, phantomjs

I have a NodeJS server (express) that serves a regular application containing an `iframe`. The JS code in the files loaded by the index page operates on that `iframe` (fetching data and injecting markup). The app works fine from a regular browser (Chrome, Firefox, ...). Now I need to run this headless, so, I devised the following plan:

- Run the page via PhantomJS
- Trigger the sequence of actions within PhantomJS via a Gulp task

The Gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('run-headless-pipeline', function() {
  console.log('Running Headless Pipeline');

  var phantomInstance;
  var page;

  phantom.create()
    .then(function (instance) {
      phantomInstance = instance;
      return phantomInstance.createPage();
    })
    .then(function (p) {
      page = p;
      page.setting('webSecurityEnabled', 'no');
      return page.open('http://localhost:3000');
    })
    .then(function (status) {
      var result;
      if(status === 'success') {
        console.log('## Status', status);

        result = page.invokeMethod('evaluate', function () {
          function0();
          function1();
          return getResults();
        });
      }
      return result;
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .then(function() { phantomInstance.exit(); })
    .catch(function (e) { console.log(e); phantomInstance.exit(); });
});
```

Where `function0()`, `function1()` and `getResults()` are methods defined in JS files loaded in the index page at `localhost:3000`. `function0` works fine, but `function1` throws an exception, the only special thing about it is that it tries to access content from the `iframe`. Problem happens in the following lines:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('targetFrame');
var targetDocument = frame.contentWindow.document;
```

In Chrome, this works fine and `targetDocument` variable contains the document in the `iframe`, in PhantomJS, `targetDocument` is `undefined`.

Throughout my search, many suggested to run PhantomJS with the parameter `--web-security` set to `false` (or `'no'`). This didn't work for me. Any ideas?

My setup is as follows:

- NodeJS v4.2.6
- Phantom module v2.1.21 (it contains phantomjs-prebuilt v2.1.4)

Comment: Try using .`contentDocument` instead of `contentWindow`

Comment: Doesn't work either!
Initially, I used `contentDocument` and it didn't work, I was advised to try `contentWindow.document`, it doesn't work as well.